# What is the route protocol in mongodb sharded cluster?

Tags: mongodb

What is the route path for a stream of data??

Let **X** represent the stream of data to be inserted.

guess 1:
1. client sends the insert request including **X** to **mongos**
2. **mongos** finds shard key range for **X** from **config db**
3. **mongos** inserts **X** to the accepted shard

guess 2:
1 and 2 are the same with guess 1
3. **mongos** returns the accepted shard to the client
4. the client inserts **X** to the accepted shard.

Whcih is the real route path or the other option??

Comment: This should be on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) since it is not about programming. But "guess1"

Comment: Client sends command to mongos -> if config server info is not cached or is expired mongos gets it -> mongos routes the command to the right shard's mongod baed on the information ascertained from the shard key in the config servers -> that shards mongod then performs the command on it's own segment of the data. This is the route

Comment: Of course if the shard is a replica set the same goes on but using the mongos C++ drivers own abilities for replica set management

Comment: Thanks! So is the i/o load of mongos server very heavy?? I remember the official docs of MongoDB suggests the mongos server can be deployed with application server.

Comment: No, the IO load is very low. None of those actions require a lot of IO, saving a single hash of the config srv once every so often is about 100th of what the OS processes do all the time, however, a MongoS can be heavy for aggregation, some aggregation will b e done through it, also it is network heavy

Comment: Reference to what I just said: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-sharded-collections/

Comment: If I insert a lot of data with large size simultaneously, I think the load on  mongos server will be quite high.